# struts2 taglib Object access in jsp

Tags: struts2, action, taglib

HI i have created one action, that contain one Document Object. I want to display those properties in jsp. i used to struts tag i am not able to get it , i am able to get string property of action , but not Object can you please help me... se my  code below. i went all suport. i am not able to fix it. i am using tomcat7 .

```
   public class SearchResultAction extends ActionSupport{
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SearchResultAction.class);
private String name;

private DocumentData documentData;



 public String execute() throws Exception {


   documentData=new DocumentData();

   documentData.setdocName("docName");
   documentData.setdDocTitle("docTitle");

   if (documentData!=null)

      {
         return SUCCESS;
      }else{
         return ERROR;  
      }
     }

public String getName() {
  return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
}

public DocumentData getDocumentData() {
    return documentData;
}

public void setDocumentData(DocumentData documentData) {
    this.documentData = documentData;
}
 }
```

My jsp code is:

```
<s:property value="documentData.docName" default="object is null"/>
```

My pojo class is:

```
 public class DocumentData {
String docName;
String dDocTitle;
String dDocDate;
String dDocAuther;
```

// setters and getters for all property
  }

Answer (score 0):

Your `docName` setter doesn't follow JavaBean conventions; does your getter?

E.g., `setdocName` should be `setDocName`, the getter `getDocName`.

OGNL is going to call `getDocName()`, if the method doesn't exist, you won't get data.

Comment: thank you very much Dave , yes Eclipse was not creating setters and getter if we have property like  dDocName . apologizes for my later response